# clod9 on EC2, accessin problems

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide

js community,

I manage to install cloud9 on my amazon EC2 Linux distribution, but Im getting a hard time trying to access it.

I start cloud9 like this 
bin/cloud9.sh -l 0.0.0.0 -p 3131
And it starts

Then I access the cloud 9 with the following url
http://ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XXX.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3131/

And it gives me the following error

```
IDE server initialized. Listening on 0.0.0.0:3131
path.exists is now called `fs.exists`.

node.js:0
// Copyright Joyent, Inc. and other Node contributors.
^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I also, open the ports with custom tcp for the port 3131, in the security groups.

Am I, missing some configuration file or anything??

Comment: Which version of node.js are you using?

Comment: last one v0.8.2 just pulled from git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comment above, you indicate that you are using node.js v0.8.2

However, cloud9 will not work on node.js v0.8.x.x, per the installation readme: https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9/blob/master/README.md

From this Github Issue page, the recommended version of node.js for cloud9 seems to be 0.6.1.9:
https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9/issues/1896

Comment: Yeahp you were right, dont know how didnt see that warning.. thanks